# Generate script in bash and save it to location requiring sudo

Tags: bash, sudo, heredoc

In bash I can create a script with a here-doc like so as per this site:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#GENERATESCRIPT

```
(
cat <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
#? [ ] / \ = + < > : ; " , * | 
#/ ? < > \ : * | ”
#Filename="z:"${$winFn//\//\\}
echo "This is a generated shell script."
App='eval wine "C:\Program Files\foxit\Foxit Reader.exe" "'$winFn'"'
$App
EOF
) > $OUTFILE
```

If my `$OUTFILE` is a directory requiring `sudo` privileges where do I put the `sudo` command or what else can I do to make it work?

Comment: I suppose one solution is to generate the file to a temporary location and then move it with sudo to the proper location.  Is that the most elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just putting `sudo` before `cat` doesn't work because `>$OUTFILE` attempts to open `$OUTFILE` in the current shell process, which is not running as root. You need the opening of that file to happen in a `sudo`-ed subprocess.

Here's one way to accomplish this:

```
sudo bash -c "cat >$OUTFILE" <<'EOF'
#!/bin/bash
#? [ ] / \ = + < > : ; " , * | 
#/ ? < > \ : * | ”
#Filename="z:"${$winFn//\//\\}
echo "This is a generated shell script."
App='eval wine "C:\Program Files\foxit\Foxit Reader.exe" "'$winFn'"'
$App
EOF
```

This starts a sub-shell under `sudo`, and opens `$OUTFILE` from that more privileged subprocess, and runs `cat` (as yet another privileged subprocess). Meanwhile, the (less privileged) parent process pipes the here-document to the `sudo` subprocess.

Comment: This works for my minimum working example but not for my actual script.  I have made my minimum working example sufficiently more complicated, can you help me with the new script?

Comment: @D W: I'd unquoted your here-word, which may have been the source of your trouble. Sorry about that. Try re-quoting it, as shown in my updated answer.

Comment: @D W: have you tried the updated answer? It works with the newer code in your question. I just went and updated it again to actually include the code from your question.

Comment: interesting that the quotes make that much difference.  Perfect, thanks.

Comment: @D W: Yeah, I was surprised by this myself. From http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections : "If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion." Useful maybe, but what a horrible syntax! My long-running theory is that most of bash syntax was designed around what was a syntax error in previous versions (with sh being the ancestral root).

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves "most of bash syntax was designed around what was a syntax error in previous versions". Hilarious and reasonable at the same time! Glorious!

Comment: PERFECT! (you don't need to quote the 'EOF' btw)

Comment: @AmirMehler Thanks. The "here word", EOF, does need to be quoted in this case. See my comment from Dec 10, '10 for details.

Answer (score 77):

This is how I would do it:

```
sudo tee "$OUTFILE" > /dev/null <<'EOF'
foo
bar
EOF
```

Comment: How do you use this method to append to an existing file?

Comment: @MountainX: `tee -a` appends to the file.

Comment: but this doesn't expand env variables ?

Comment: Mihai:  That's correct, quoting the `'EOF'` disables expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `dd` for that:

```
sudo dd of="$OUTFILE" <<EOF
foo
bar
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Non of the answers expanded environment variables. My workaround is a tmp file and a sudo mv.

```sh
l_log=/var/log/server/server.log
l_logrotateconf=/etc/logrotate.d/server
tmp=/tmp/$$.eof
cat << EOF > $tmp
$l_log {
   rotate 12
   monthly
   compress
   missingok
   notifempty
}
EOF
sudo mv $tmp $logrotateconf
```