# AWS EMR bootstrap action as sudo

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, sudo, amazon-emr

I need to update `/etc/hosts` for all instances in my EMR cluster (EMR AMI 4.3).

The whole script is nothing more than:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e 'ip1 uri1' >> /etc/hosts
echo -e 'ip2 uri2' >> /etc/hosts
...
```

This script needs to run as `sudo` or it fails.

From here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html#bootstrapUses

> Bootstrap actions execute as the Hadoop user by default. You can execute a bootstrap action with root privileges by using **sudo**.

Great news...  but I can't figure out how to do this, and I can't find an example.

I've tried a bunch of things...  including...

- running as Hadoop and adding 'sudo' to each of the 'echo' statements in the script
- using a shell script to copy and chmod the above ('echo' statements with no 'sudo') and running local copy using run-if bootstrap that calls `1=1 sudo bash /home/hadoop/myDir/myScript.sh`
- hard coding the whole script as a one-liner into a run-if bootstrap action

I consistently get:

> On the master instance (i-xxx), bootstrap action 2 returned a non-zero return code

If i check the logs for the "Setup hadoop debugging" step, there's nothing there.

From here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-overview.html#emr-overview-cluster-lifecycle

summary emr setup (in order):

1. provisions ec2 instances
2. **runs bootstrap actions**
3. installs native applications...  like **hadoop**, spark, etc.

So it seems like there's some risk that since I'm mucking around as user Hadoop before hadoop is installed, I could be messing something up there, but I can't imagine what.

I think it must be that my script isn't running as 'sudo' and it's failing to update `/etc/hosts`.

My question...  how can I use bootstrap actions (or something else) on EMR to run a simple shell script as sudo?  ...specifically to update `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: I've not had problems using sudo within EMR bootstrap actions. If you launch a cluster, then SSH into one of the nodes as hadoop, can you sudo? Can you try with a trivial BA that does cat /etc/hosts and then sudo cat /etc/hosts with a sprinkling of echo "I'm now about to do X" to debug progress.

Comment: if I ssh in, it's no problem to run commands as 'sudo'.  i'll run some trivial examples like you suggest and see if I can run them without the cluster terminating due to bootstrap error so i can view results.  One question...  you say "I've not had problems using sudo w/in EMR bootstrap actions."  Do you mean that you've used 'sudo' in the shell script, and the script runs ok by default (as user Hadoop)?

Comment: Correct, shell scripts run as BAs where the shell scripts invoke sudo for certain commands.

Comment: did what you suggested.  `cat /etc/hosts` and `sudo cat /etc/hosts` and echo's all ran fine and output was in /mnt/var/log/bootstrap-actions/1 for both master and executors.  however, on existing cluster, as Hadoop...  tried running shell script with `sudo echo -e 'ip1 uri1' >> /etc/hosts` and it runs ok when run as sudo, but fails when run as hadoop with error message `/etc/hosts: Permission denied`

Comment: Try: sudo sh -c 'echo -e "ip1 uri1" >> /etc/hosts'

Comment: In addition to jarmod's answer below, if you're running a command with a heredoc, you can follow this answer to solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4412091/1994092

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've not had problems using sudo from within a shell script run as an EMR bootstrap action, so it should work. You can test that it works with a simple script that simply does "sudo ls /root".

Your script is trying to append to /etc/hosts by redirecting stdout with:

```
sudo echo -e 'ip1 uri1' >> /etc/hosts
```

The problem here is that while the echo is run with sudo, the redirection (>>) is not. It's run by the underlying hadoop user, who does not have permission to write to /etc/hosts. The fix is:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo -e "ip1 uri1" >> /etc/hosts'
```

This runs the entire command, including the stdout redirection, in a shell with sudo.